# ExpressJS - JWT and Passport Implementation

Tags: express, authentication, token, jwt, passport.js

I'm currently trying to learn JWT and Passport for ExpressJS while trying them out but I can't seem to grasp the idea of how Passport works.

Here's what I have done initially in my ExpressJS application.

`/api/login` `POST` API

- Accepts username and password
- `/api/login` then creates a JWT with the username and password as the payload
- The token is then responded to the client

I think my `/api/login` API simulates the general idea of JWT of hard authenticate once and respond with token.

`/api/test` `GET` API on the other hand

- Only authenticated users can access
- Simply returns "Hello World!"

What is the problem/s?

- My code doesn't seem to validate the token (I tried putting the token in Authenticate header.
- Where in my request should I include the token returned from `/api/login` when requesting to `/api/test`?

Now to my actual code:

`app.js`

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
var passport = require("passport");
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mySecret = "mySecret";
var app = express();
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function (token, done) {
        var credentials = jwt.verify(token, mySecret);
        if (credentials.username == "test" && credentials.password == "test") {
            return done(null, credentials);
        } else {
            return done(null, false);
        }
    }
));

app.use(passport.initialize());

app.post("/api/login", function (request, response) {
    var user = {
        "username": request.body.username,
        "password": request.body.password
    };
    response.send(jwt.sign(user, "mySecret"));
});

app.get("/api/test", passport.authenticate("local", {
    "session": false
}), function (request, response) {
    response.send("Hello World!");
});

app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log("Listening on port: " + port);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to configure **jwtStratagy** also to authenticate the user. 
here is working example: -

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
console.log(jwt.verify);
const passport = require("passport"),
  LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(passport.initialize());
var secret = '11210646';
var JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy,
  ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: 'username',
    passwordField: 'password',
    passReqToCallback: true
  },
  function(req, username, password, done) {
    console.log('ohh', username, password);
    let err = null;
    if (err) { return done(err); }
    if (username != 'abhi') {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
    }
    if (password != 'pass') {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
    }
    return done(null, username);

  }
));
app.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    console.log(err, user, info);
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { res.send({ "status": info.message }); }
    res.send({ "status": user });
  })(req, res, next);
});
var opts = {
  jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
  secretOrKey: secret,
  issuer: 'jonu',
  audience: 'jonu bhai',
  passReqToCallback: false
};
app.post('/me2', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }, function(err,user, info) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    if (!user) { res.send({ "status": info.message }); }
    res.send({ "status": user });
  })(req, res, next);

});
//jwt

passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, function(jwt_payload, done) {
  let err = null;
  if (err) {
    return done(err, false);
  }
  if (jwt_payload) {
    return done(null, jwt_payload);
  }
  else {
    return done(null, false);
    // or you could create a new account
  }

}));


app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {

  let token = jwt.sign({
      user: {
        id: "idididid",
        name: "Abhishek Singh",
        username: "abhishek11210646"
      }
    },
    secret, {
      algorithm: 'HS256',
      expiresIn: '5h',
      issuer: 'jonu',
      audience: 'jonu bhai'
    });
  res.send({ "token": token });
});

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send({ "status": "Up and Running..." });
});

app.listen(8080, () => {
  console.log('server running');
});
```

Comment: Hey @Abhishek, I got it to work after using jwtStrategy. Just to add on your answer, I'm currently using ExtractJWT.fromAuthHeaderWithScheme("jwt") as my extractor. Implementing the same extractor will require the client to concat "jwt<white_space>" before the token.  Thanks @Abhishek!

Comment: Yes, code return in aswer will require the client to concat "Bearer <white_space>" before the token.